# How eliminate codes with format 00.00.00A

Tags: r

I want to eliminate some rows from a data.frame with one of the variable with format 00.00.00U, e.g. eliminating a vector containing:

```
 toMatch<-paste(c(18.00.00:20.00.00),c('U','B','R'))
 Errore: unexpected numeric constant in "toMatch<-paste(c(18.00.00"
```

I need to eliminate `18.00.01`, `18.00.02` etc until `20.00.00` and i don't want to write them all.
thanks

Comment: that's another matter but your pattern doesn't seem to contain a space between the series of numbers and the letter (as in your example `00.00.00U`) so you'll need to specify `sep=""`in your `paste` instruction

Comment: I want to use the annotation : .like it use for eliminate numbers from 18 to 20, (18:20) but for this code-numbers from 18.00.00 to 20.00.00 something like (18.00.00:20.00.00), class of this variable "CHOPCODES" is "character". Sorry for my bad english

Comment: It is not a date, so i cant'use the time annotation. There are Operation Codes like 18.98.87U in which U is e.g. for unknown

Comment: or 'B' for bilareral, L for left, R for Right. The side where the Operation was taken

Comment: There are some codes with 18.87B and some others more specific mayby like 18.87.99B, and there are also other numbers like 09000 and so on, so its a mix. The Problem it i cannot separate them, e.g. in some rows i have in the same field 18.87B,18.87.99B,0900L

Comment: Yes there are other patterns, but i can eliminate them without problem, what i not can eliminate are the codes like 19.99.87B

Answer (score 0):

You first have to generate the codes :

```
codes<-sapply(180001:200000,
             function(x){
                decomp<-unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),""))
                y<-paste(paste(decomp[seq(1,6,2)],decomp[seq(2,6,2)],sep=""),collapse=".")
                return(y)})
```

Then you can do :

```
toMatch<-paste(rep(codes,e=3),c('U','B','R'),sep="")

toMatch[1:5]
[1] "18.00.01U" "18.00.01B" "18.00.01R" "18.00.02U" "18.00.02B"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
op <- options(scipen=100, digits=2)
s1 <- seq(180001, 200000, by=1)

s2 <- sprintf('%02d.%02d.%02d', 
                          as.numeric(substr(s1,1,2)),
                          as.numeric(substr(s1,3,4)),
                          as.numeric(substr(s1,5,6)))
toMatch <- paste0(s2, rep(c('U', 'B', 'R'),each=length(s2)))
head(toMatch)
#[1] "18.00.01U" "18.00.02U" "18.00.03U" "18.00.04U" "18.00.05U" "18.00.06U"
```

If `df` is the dataset and if you wanted to remove the rows that match the elements in `toMatch` with a particular column `Col1`

```
df1 <- df[!df$Col1 %in% toMatch, ]
```

Comment: I tried, but when i want to eliminate the rows with the command

Comment: > ifelse(minLL$X1000R, minLLr<-minLL[!grepl(paste(toMatch3, collapse= "|"), minLL$CHOPCODES), ], plot(r))
Errore in grepl(paste(toMatch3, collapse = "|"), minLL$CHOPCODES) : 
  invalid regular expression '18.00.01U|18.00.01B|

Comment: i tried, but when i want to eliminate the rows with the command       > ifelse(minLL$X1000R, minLLr<-minLL[!grepl(paste(toMatch3, collapse= "|"), minLL$CHOPCODES), ], plot(r))
Errore in grepl(paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"), minLL$CHOPCODES) : 
  invalid regular expression '18.00.01U|18.00.01B|...and so on

Comment: to search a pattern. are there other Options?

Comment: I think size isn't the issue, it comes out: Warning message:
In rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

Comment: @LéTr'k, have you tried my code ? does it work for you ?

Comment: @CathG i have tried your solution and it comes also the same output if i trie my ifelse-loop:                               ifelse(minLL$X1000R, minLLr<-minLL[!grepl(paste(toMatch3, collapse= "|"), minLL$CHOPCODES), ], plot(r))                               Errore in grepl(paste(toMatch, collapse = "|"), minLL$CHOPCODES): invalid regular expression '18.00.01U|18.00.01B|...and so on

Comment: @LéTr'k, ok, I thought the purpose was only to get the ToMatch vector. Maybe you should edit your question to add the other problem ?

Comment: I think the problem is that the variable where i want to eliminate the row with the code is character-class. It is possible?

Comment: @akrun, yes, that what I figured out too, and our codes do answer the OP question... but the true question is apparently the one that is not asked

Comment: @Lé Tr'k Please provide some reproducible example.